# Provider error '80004005' Unspecified error

Tags: asp.net

I know this question has been asked before but i can't seem to see from the other posts what this could be i don't know asp i have just been uploading images and changing the database and re uploading via FTP but now i have come across a error

> Provider error '80004005'
>
> Unspecified error
>
> /Includes/DB/DatabaseConnect.asp, line 8

```
 <% 
    Dim espostiDB 
    Set espostiDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    'espostiDB.ConnectionString = "DSN=esposti.dsn"
    'espostiDB.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("db\esposti1.mdb")
    espostiDB.ConnectionString = "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ=" & Server.MapPath("db\esposti.mdb") ')e:\inetpub\wwwroot\esposti\esposti.mdb" 
    'espostiDB.ConnectionString = "DSN=esposti.dsn"
    espostiDB.Open
%>
```

> line 8 is espostiDB.open
>
> Database is Access 2000

Help Much appreciated

Jack

Comment: Use ADO.NET providers - Oledb or Odbc instead of ADODB.

Comment: Looking at the code above is it esposti1.mdb or esposti.mdb you are trying to access?

Comment: esposti.mdb, i don't know what the esposti1.mdb is, AVD - how would i implement that? i have no idea about ASP

Comment: Server.MapPath("db\esposti.mdb") - Try Server.MapPath("~\db\esposti.mdb")

Comment: I dont understand why i would need to change any code because it was all working fine a hour ago - il try that now bgs264

Comment: Sorted it! I just changed what bgs264 said uploaded it it didn't work unfortunately so i re uploaded the database connect.asp original file and its now working! STrange very strange! but thanks for you help guys!

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved this problem, the exact same error. Went to Control Panel - Administrative Tools - Internet information Services. On the right click View Application Pools and for both "Classic NET AppPool" and "DefaultAppPool" set v4.0 network framework version. If it's set to v2.0 the error above will show up.

Answer (score 1):

Working with your code above, you could use this:

```
<% 
    Set espostiDB = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

    connStr = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & Server.MapPath("~\db\esposti.mdb")

    espostiDB.Open connStr
%>
```

The info [here](http://asp.weppos.com/asp/scripts/oledb-access-database-connection) will also give you some pointers of how to work Server.MapPath (in case your mdb file is not in the root of your website).

Answer (score 1):

80004005 errors can be numerous things, one thing to check is that the database is not currently in an open state and therefore locked, so every time you open a connection you need to make sure that you close it.  An easy way to check this is to check if there is an Access lock file (.ldb) file in the same folder as the database.

Check that you've not inadvertently changed the path so it's now incorrect (a `Response.Write(Server.MapPath("db\esposti.mdb"))`) should print the full path.

Also, worth recycling the IIS app pool, sometimes connections remain open in IIS and the database becomes unresponsive, this can be a sign you're not closing connections properly.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this conflicts looks to be 32 Bit Application running on the 64 Bit. Please make sure that the ODBC connection is described at C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe